# Pyspark dataframe OrderBy list of columns

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to use OrderBy function in pyspark dataframe before I write into csv but I am not sure to use OrderBy functions if I have a list of columns.

**Code:**

```
Cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df = df.OrderBy(cols,ascending=False)
```

Comment: This thread is wrongly marked as duplicate. Question for [40467449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467449/how-to-select-and-order-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-after-a-join) deals with ordering of columns in dataframe select. This question deals with ordering of rows inside a dataframe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per docstring / signature:

> ```
> Signature: df.orderBy(*cols, **kwargs)
> Docstring:
> Returns a new :class:`DataFrame` sorted by the specified column(s).
> :param cols: list of :class:`Column` or column names to sort by.
> :param ascending: boolean or list of boolean (default True).
> ```

Both

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3)] )
cols = ["_1", "_2", "_3"]

df.orderBy(cols, ascending=False)
```

and

```
df.orderBy(*cols, ascending=False)
```

are valid, as well as equivalents with `list[pyspark.sql.Column]`.